# dynamic salt to password hash

Tags: c#, encryption

Im completely new to this topic, but i have made a login for my website, where naturally the users password upon registration is encrypted and put into my sql database. I have the following method for encryption here:

```
public static string Encrypt(string clearText)
{
    string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
    byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
    using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
        return clearText;
}
```

There are however several problems with this way of encrypting / decrypting a password.

1. The salt is not random - which means that similar passwords looks the same when hashed, which is a problem if one of these passwords are cracked, the other are cracked too.
2. The encryption key is inside my method, which means that it is accessible and easy for a hacker to get.

These two stated assumptions, are just a "beginners" thought. Im not completely sure if my concerns are valid.

However, if they are, how would i do this, in the most "responsible" way? I have read about dynamic salts, and it seems like a solid way to come around this.

Comment: Where is salt here?

Comment: `Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });`

Comment: But why do you encrypt password to store in database? Just hash it (with random salt which also store in database). You don't need to ever _decrypt_ user's password.

Comment: i guess i could just compare the hashes upon login yes! But anyways, how would that work with a dynamic salt? i cant seem to understand the logic behind it. (if it compares the hash, how can it figure out the salt?)

Comment: You generate random salt, hash password combined with salt and store both hash AND salt in database, together. Then when user logs in - you take his password and salt you store for this particular user. Hash again (salt is the same) and compare with hash stored for that user.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend that you find a pre-rolled authentication mechanism here rather than trying to build this yourself. You're making several basic mistakes (such as planning to encrypt rather than to hash) and the likelihood is that, even after receiving help from random strangers on the internet, there'll still be implementation mistakes that render the overall result insecure. Find something that others have already built and is generally trusted.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thank you very much for your answer! Im thinking about rolling with that aswell.. However, im trying to learn, thats why i asked in the first place. - Where would i find such? i mean, with my vague knowledge on this topic, i might choose a less secure one :-)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You refering to something like https://github.com/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel ?

Comment: just a method that i can implement, is what i thought

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever To follow up, after researching for a while on this topic i actually found something very useful. Take a look: 

https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm
https://github.com/defuse/password-hashing

This class is extremely easy to implement, and does exactly do the job!

Comment: Which class is that then?